# Angular2: How is Kendo passing multiple components with the same selector?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm looking at Kendo's Angular2 components, specifically this grid feature, and they have multiple `kendo-grid-column` components in the same component

```
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="Discontinued" width="120">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

I'm assuming they are not using `ng-content` and transclusion to implement this, as when I attempt something similar, the content I project all gets thrown into the first ng-content.

Here is what my parent.component.html looks like:

```
<app-side-pane *ngIf="tester">
  <app-side-pane-header
    [employeeName]="employee.formattedName"
    [employeeStatus]="employee.employeeStatus"
    [employeeImage]=""
    [employeeTitle]="employee.jobTitle"
    [employeeCountry]="employee.homeCountry"
  ></app-side-pane-header>
  <app-side-pane-body>
    <app-side-pane-body-slide [slideTitle]="'Reference Data'">
      <app-side-pane-body-slide-item></app-side-pane-body-slide-item>
    </app-side-pane-body-slide>
    <app-side-pane-body-slide [slideTitle]="'Foo Bar'"></app-side-pane-body-slide>
  </app-side-pane-body>
</app-side-pane>
```

And here is my app-side-pane-body.html:

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="boxcontent" >
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <ng-content></ng-content>

      </div>
      <!-- Add Pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

dupe.png
[image]

Comment: `field="ProductID"` of `kendo-grid-column` defines its uniqueness, as table can have multiple columns..

Comment: @PankajParkar, for `app-side-pane-body-slide` the slideTitle is the unique for each component, however, the content is being shown in the same component, which isn't expected.

Comment: Can you show us what's wrong here? transclusion makes perfect sense as it just wraps the content inside of it. So I'm having a hard time imagining the issue.

Comment: @MichaelSolati, the issue I'm having is that when I inject multiple `app-side-pane-body-slide`s into the `<app-side-pane-body>`, where inside `<app-side-pane-body>` is using transclusion via `<ng-content>`, the `<app-side-pane-body-slide>`s get merged into the the same component (see dupe.png) and are not separate slides. Does this help? If not, I can rewrite the question.